# Calling https.get using nodejs from a function?

Tags: node.js, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to write my first Alexa Skill and I am doing an http request which works fine, however I would like to wrap this into a function that I can call from my main code.

It is not working and I am not quite sure how I can store the response into a variable, here is my code so far:

```
function getValue(loc) {
    var endpoint = 'URLHERE'
    var something = ""
    var body = ""
    https.get(endpoint, (response) => {
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body += chunk
        })
        response.on('end', () => {
            data = JSON.parse(body)
            something = data.result.node.value;
        })
    })
    return something;
}
```

This is on amazon and using lambda for the functions using node.js

which I call `getValue('test')` using

```
var result = getValue('test')
```

it just returned undefined.

Any idea's? Thanks

I imagine because its an asynchronous call its not setting the value due to callback but I have tried implementing this and cannot get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning from your function before the callback of http.get, mixing Synchronous with Asynchronous behaviour.

So your function is `return`ing `something` which hasn't been defined yet.

Try this instead :

```
function getValue(loc,cb) {
    let endpoint = 'URLHERE'
    let something = ""
    let body = ""
    https.get(endpoint, (response) => {
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body += chunk
        })
        response.on('end', () => {
            data = JSON.parse(body)
            cb(data.result.node.value);
        })
    })
}

getValue(test,(result)=>{
   //do something with result here;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours of trying this callback's have finally clicked! :) Thanks xShirease